# Browser equivalent of Node JS assert library

Tags: javascript, node.js, assert

Is there a good port of [Node JS's assert](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) that I can access from a CDN and run in a browser?

I have seen https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert but I am not using browserify so I don't think that I can use that one.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful to you. Take a look at this git repo - [jest-lite](https://github.com/kvendrik/jest-lite). Says it allows you to run jest in the browser and has a CDN.

An example from the site:

```
import {describe, it, expect, run} from 'jest-lite';

function sum(x: number, y: number) {
  return x + y;
}

describe('sum', () => {
  it('adds the two given numbers', () => {
    expect(sum(2, 2)).toBe(4);
  });
});

const result = await run();
console.log(result);
```

See the docs for more.

Good luck